# Media query is not working when i try to change the color

Tags: html, css, media-queries

1.mediaquery.css

```
body {
  color: red;
}
.title {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

[image: Link to screen]

Media query is not working when I try to change the color it should change to blue but it is not changing the color when getting down to max-width which is 500px;

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: You probably have a text color set with higher specificity further down the cascade. For example `<p>` set to color: #000.; or a more broadly affected area below body in the hierarchy, like main { color: #000; }. Need to see the full code in order to help further.

Comment: Hi, the code you have given works fine. You need to include enough code, in a snippet, which shows the error.

Answer (score 1):

Use just `@media` instead of `@media all`.
I have run a sample code down here using just @media you can check.

```css
body{
  background-color: blue;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px){
  body{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello this is my code</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: `@media screen` would be even better.

Comment: Yes, we can use `@media Screen` also, This is also Working

Comment: Yes of course, this is working. I just pointed out a 'more specific' possibility. @RahulNikam